# instead for, array foreach on Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

functional programing like the big wave that effect our coding habit,like `forEach`.

Despite `For` in javascript is pretty convenient and util. I want the whole loop look like `functional` so I set the array to stead for `let index = 0...`:

**pure javscript**

```
for(let index = 0;index < 10;index++){
   //count 10 times.
}
```

**functional Solution**

```
Array(10).forEach((value,index,arr)=>{
  //count 10 times. 
})
```

When array is made that empty items in self, So I use `fill` to solve this problem, the `fill` made `functional` complex.

Is any way to make item in `Array` or instead `for` cleary?

Comment: supported the solution code : 
`Array(10).fill().forEach(()=>{})`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: want to use `foreach` to achieve the `for` ,like I set `10` and it would run 10 times.

Comment: It is a serious kludge to create an array so you can use *forEach* instead of a plain *for* loop. It will also likely run more slowly. Consider `for(let i=10; --i;){}` which is less to type and more performant.

Comment: @RobG hi rob, Is new the array and took memory that effect the performace?

Comment: It's likely not an issue as a one off, but if you're doing it in many places, and with large loops, certainly.

Comment: @RachChen all the functions like `forEach`, `,map` are meant to make data manipulation more readable. They are never meant to replace `for` or `while`. The objective of these functions is, make reading easy. So If I read, `array.filter(...)` I will just look at condition and understand its purpose. Same thing, if implemented using for will be less readable as I will have to read entire thing.

Comment: Also, you can't (sensibly) break out of *forEach*, it must run for the entire length, it can't replace *do* or *while* loops.

Comment: If you want to toy around, you could e.g. write `repeat = (cb, n) => { while (n-- > 0) cb(n) }; repeat((n) => console.log(n), 5);` - for real productive code I'd go with fast, simple for-loops.

Comment: `forEach` is for side-effects; it's not functional

Comment: Is duplicate ? I even didn't see any pure `functional` solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write in a truly functional manner, you might want to implement it yourself:

```
function range(n){
    if(n <= 0)  return [];
    else        return range(n-1).concat([n]);
}

range(10).forEach(n => /* do stuff */);
```

Keep in mind that, if your code is truly functional, there shouldn't be a need for a `forEach` loop because it will only cause side effects, and you don't want that in functional programming.

Comment: Wouldn't this be done using `Array(10).fill(0)` or `Array.from()` ?

Comment: Hassam, explain why you should allocate and initialize an *array* with values before we can begin looping